# Multiple pods/micro-services update/insert the same record

Tags: java, database, hibernate, mariadb, microservices

I have multiple services both receiving the requests
Sample request has 3 fields - Currency, Date, Amount

**Existing table has 2 entries**

*Key, Currency, Date, Amount*

123, USD, 1 Aug, 100

234, EUR, 1 Dec, 50

**Insert Case**

If no entry exists in the table with the received Currency, Date combination, a new entry is inserted.
e.g. For above table, if we receive (USD, 2 Aug, 20), new entry will be inserted

**Update Case**

If an entry already exists in the table with the received Currency, Date combination existing entry is updated by updating the Amount field
e.g. For above table, if we receive (USD, 1 Aug, 30), the existing entry will 123 will be updated and the updated amount will be 100+30 = 130

**Scenario Problem**

There are 3 instances of the services running in kubernetes/similar platform and below three services receives requests around same time
First service receives request (USD, 1 Sep, 100)
Second service receives request (USD, 1 Sep, 200)
Third service receives request (USD, 1 Sep, 300)

Ideal case should be, whichever services processes first, will create the first insert entry, and the remaining two services will update the amount for that entry

Desired end result:

USD, 1 Sep, 600

But, one of the observed results is, where 2 services ends up inserting the record and depending on the application layer handling, the 3rd entry can fail as it won't find the unique entry to update the amount or it ends up updating one of the returned entry from the database based

USD, 1 Sep, 100

USD, 1 Sep, 500

**Queston**

How and where should this be handled? In the database using locks or at the Java application layer?

Comment: How can 2 services end up inserting the record? Does your database not have a unique constraint?

Comment: It does not have unique constraint currently. So, If the unique constraint is added, for above scenario, on (Currency, Date), then the insertion can be prevented?

Also, the other service which will try to insert the record will fail as the entry was already inserted by the first service. In this case, how to retry and update the record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a concurrency problem, I suppose that you are doing two queries to do this. First, you try to find the record in the database, and second, you do an update or an insert depending on if it exists or not.
However, if the two requests arrive at the same time (or nearly the same time) the two make the first query and because this currency does not exist, they do the insert.

To solve this, I will add a unique constraint in the currency, as Kayaman suggests, and change the query to be an upsert (it is a combination of update and insert query that is supported in some databases) to make the query atomic so if the insert fails because there is already a record with the same currency it will do an update

Here is the documentation about how to do an upsert in Postgresql
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/